# serverless: deploy lambda with code from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have aws codebuild hooked up to my git repo keeping my lambda function code up to date with each merge, I'd like to automate the process of refreshing the code in my lambdas using serverless.

Right now I use serverless to create my DBs & S3 buckets, but I'd like to be able to deploy my lambdas and attribute the function code to a specific zip file in an S3 bucket as well -- is this possible? If so, what would the lambda's serverless yml look like?

Cheers,
-E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serverless.yml will look something like this:

```
service: my-service

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - any-other-plugin

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-1
  memorySize: 128 # optional, in MB, default is 1024
  timeout: 120 # optional, in seconds, default is 6
  deploymentBucket:
    name: YOUR_BUCKET_NAME
  iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      - "dynamodb:Query" 
      - "another:action" 
    Resource: resource_name

environment:
      VAR1: VALUE1
      VAR2: VALUE2
      VAR3: VALUE3

functions:
  lambda-function-name:
    handler: filename.function
    timeout: 900
```

Comment: After I push an update to GIT and it triggers codebuild and a new zip file is added to my S3 bucket if I rerun this it'll refresh the lambda?

I'll test soon, but wanted to ask in the interim